# Mysql query to get last status value entered

Tags: mysql

I've a table like this -

```
+----+---------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| id | check_date          | number     | status  | sid                |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|  5 | 2012-09-29 17:44:34 | 3366064235 | SUCCESS | 1348940709163284   |
|  6 | 2012-09-29 19:40:30 | 3366064235 | FAILED  | 12345678876543     |
|  7 | 2012-09-29 17:47:30 | 4466064235 | SUCCESS | 7895345678876543   |
|  8 | 2012-09-29 19:47:30 | 4466064235 | SUCCESS | 789876545678876543 |
+----+---------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+
```

I want to get last updated status of each number. How do I get this? I tried group by number order by check_date desc but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select t1.id, 
    t1.check_date,
    t1.number,
    t1.status
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
    select max(check_date) maxdate, number
    from yourtable
    group by number
) t2
    on t1.check_date = t2.maxdate
    and t1.number = t2.number
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb084/1)

Comment: Can't we do this without using a subquery?

Comment: @Shwetanka it depends on what you want to return, if you only want the date and the number then yes, but it you want to know the status, the group by will make them distinct. See this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb084/7.  Either way you will need some kind of subquery either via a `JOIN` or in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select number, Status, Check_date from MYTable A
where check_date = (select max(Check_date) from MYTable where number=A.number)
```